# Custom image upload adapter ckeditor 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor5

I am trying to make it work (Custom image upload adapter) by docs. But I have an error.

I left only simple code to be sure that it is not the environment, but I have the same error.

Sorry, I don't know why but I could not put the code inside this editor correctly so I just put it into the snippet.

After choosing a photo I have an error.

> ckeditorerror.js:46 Uncaught CKEditorError: model-selection-set-ranges-not-range: Selection range set to an object that is not an instance of model.Range.

Interesting that if I add some text before I have another error.

> ckeditorerror.js:46 Uncaught CKEditorError: model-createPositionAt-offset-required: Model#createPositionAt() requires the offset when the first parameter is a model item.

```js
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote';
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor';
import BalloonEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-balloon/src/ballooneditor';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload';
import UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-adapter-ckfinder/src/uploadadapter';
import CKFinder from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder/src/ckfinder';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading';
import leftIcon from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-left.svg';
import rightIcon from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/theme/icons/object-right.svg';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link';
import Highlight from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight/src/highlight';
import FontSize from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font/src/fontsize';


class MyUploadAdapter {
    constructor(loader) {
        this.loader = loader;
    }

    upload() {
        return this.loader.file
            .then(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this._initRequest();
                this._initListeners(resolve, reject, file);
                this._sendRequest(file);
            }));
    }

    abort() {
        if (this.xhr) {
            this.xhr.abort();
        }
    }

    _initRequest() {
        const xhr = this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://****/ajax/upload-ckeditor-image', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
    }

    _initListeners(resolve, reject, file) {
        const xhr = this.xhr;
        const loader = this.loader;
        const genericErrorText = `Couldn't upload file: ${file.name}.`;

        xhr.addEventListener('error', () => reject(genericErrorText));
        xhr.addEventListener('abort', () => reject());
        xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const response = xhr.response;

            if (!response || response.error) {
                return reject(response && response.error ? response.error.message : genericErrorText);
            }

            resolve({
                default: response.url
            });
        });

        if (xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    loader.uploadTotal = evt.total;
                    loader.uploaded = evt.loaded;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    _sendRequest(file) {
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('upload', file);
        this.xhr.send(data);
    }
}


function MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin(editor) {
    editor.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
        return new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
    };
}


ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'), {
        plugins: [
            Table,
            TableToolbar,
            Essentials,
            Paragraph,
            Bold,
            Italic,
            Heading,
            Image,
            ImageToolbar,
            ImageCaption,
            ImageStyle,
            ImageUpload,
            UploadAdapter,
            Link,
            Highlight,
            List,
            BlockQuote,
            FontSize
        ],
        extraPlugins: [MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin],
        toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'imageUpload', 'fontSize', 'heading', 'link', 'highlight', 'bulletedList',
            'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'undo', 'redo', 'insertTable']

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

```html
<textarea name="editor" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

I don't know what to do because I just took basic code from docs and did't add anything special from myself.
I have tried to update npm , nodemodules and etc. but it didn't help.
npm -v 6.9.0
node -v v9.11.2

Comment: Have a look at this, https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-model-selection-set-ranges-not-range
This is regarding first error that you mentioned. Check if there are `multiple ckeditor5-engine packages having different versions.` as mentioned at above url.

Comment: I didn't want to find out what was the problem with dependencies so I just dropped everything, made working version of uploading photo and than step by step added all my extra plugins. In the process I found out that you also have to add @ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/filerepository plugin. It was not so clear for me from the docs.

Comment: So in case if you were able to solve this problem, you can put your solution as an answer to this question. It will help others as well.

Comment: Actually, that's not true that you have to add `FileRepository`. It's a dependency of `ImageUpload`, so it's loaded automatically. The issue may be that you used `config.plugins` **and** `config.extraPlugins`. Does putting all of them in `config.plugins` help?

Comment: Another option – you have outdated dependencies. Perhaps you upgraded some of CKE5 packages while not others. Run a tool like [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to verify that, remove `node_modules` and install everything again.